# Google script. get an array with part of string

Tags: string, google-apps-script, text, lookup

I have a spreadhseet where i have the following link in 1 cell:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, https://drive.google.com/open?id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I need an array of the X part and the Y part.

```
body.editAsText().appendText(myimage.match(/[\w\_\-]{33,}/).toString());

body.editAsText().appendText(myimage[0]);
body.editAsText().appendText(myimage[1]);
```

Both of these lines bring the same line xxxxxx.....

Comment: Try `const text = body.editAsText(); text.appendText(myimage[0]);text.appendText(myimage[1]);` and using the `text` afterwards.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] with real data

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const v = sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();//https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, https://drive.google.com/open?id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
  const arr = v.split(',').map((e => e.trim().split("=")[1]));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
7:05:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:05:29 PM  Info    ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"]
7:05:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const v = sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();//https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, https://drive.google.com/open?id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
  const arr = v.split(',').map((e => e.trim().split("=")[1]));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
7:05:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:05:29 PM  Info    ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"]
7:05:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)